# How to set active item index in pnp/spfx carousel?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, react

I am using Pnp/spfx Carousel control and binding elements like below:

```
 <Carousel
                        buttonsLocation={CarouselButtonsLocation.center}
                        buttonsDisplay={CarouselButtonsDisplay.block}
                        containerButtonsStyles={styles.carouselButtonsContainer}
                        isInfinite={false}
                        interval={null}
                        prevButtonStyles={styles.preSlide}
                        nextButtonStyles={styles.nextSlide}
                        indicatorShape={CarouselIndicatorShape.circle}
                        indicatorClassName={styles.customIndicator}
                        element={this.state.allItems} // applying JSX element
                        onMoveNextClicked={(index: number) => { }}
                        onMovePrevClicked={(index: number) => { }}
                    />
```

Now I want to display a specific item in Carousel control using a dropdown onchange by setting the item idex.
Kindly help me to set the current display index in Carousel control.